# Socialite: Merge accounts that have the same email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

im using socialite to give the users the option to log in with either facebook or github. but when a user logs in with facebook and after that with github, 2 separate accounts are created. So my question is , is there a way to combine these 2 accounts into one? for example if a user that has logged in with facebook is using the same email address to log in with github, no new account will be created and they will simply be logged in

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('profile');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('provider_id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

login/register code

```
/**
 * Redirect the user to the provider authentication page.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from the provider.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $SocialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    $user = $this -> findOrCreateUser($SocialUser,$provider);

    auth()->login($user,true);


    return redirect('/');

}

protected function findOrCreateUser($SocialUser,$provider)
{
    $user = User::firstOrNew(['provider_id' => $SocialUser->id]);

        if ($user->exists) return $user;
    $user->fill([
    'name' => $SocialUser->nickname?:$SocialUser->name,
    'slug' => str_slug($SocialUser->nickname?:$SocialUser->name).'-'.uniqid(),
        'email' => $SocialUser->email,
        'avatar' => $SocialUser->avatar,
        'profile' => Hash::make('no pic'),
        'password' => Hash::make('no need for password token based'),
    // 'website' => 'add a website',
    // 'github_profile' => 'add github profile',
    'email_notifications' => 1
    ])->save();
    $user->assignRole('user');
    \Mail::to($user)->send(new Welcome($user));
    session()->flash('message','Welcome to '.config('app.name').' '.$user->name);
    return $user;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Kristi Can you please post what your user table looks like?

Comment: hi. just added my users table above

Comment: what you can do is, instead of using only one `provider_id`, use `facebook_id`, `github_id` and `twitter_id` to store them individually

Comment: Hi Kristi Can you please add some examples of the data that has duplicated?

Comment: @josh im loggin in/registering users based on the provider id. so im checking if the provider id exists in the db then login the user otherwise create a new user.

Comment: @joe how would that make a difference?

Comment: ive added the login/register code above

Comment: @kristi Well according to the migration that you have provided you can't have 2 entries with  the same email and so you should not be getting duplicate user accounts

Comment: @josh im sorry the migration is a little outdated. i had to change the table manually and im allowing dublicate emails. im sorry about that. didnt notice

Comment: @kristitanellari use `User::where('email', $SocialUser->email)->first()` rather than checking for provider_id

Comment: @kristi I came to the same conclusion as Joe. Also the way you have written it it would log every user into first person to use that provider. see my solution below

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that's using the spirit of everything in this question and answer.

```
/**
 * @param  string $provider
 * @param  \Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User $sUser
 * @return \App\User|false
 */
protected function findOrCreateUser($provider, $sUser)
{
    $oauthProvider = OAuthProvider::where('provider', $provider)
        ->where('provider_user_id', $sUser->id)
        ->first();

    if ($oauthProvider) {
        $oauthProvider->update([
            'access_token' => $sUser->token,
            'refresh_token' => $sUser->refreshToken ?? null,
        ]);

        return $oauthProvider->user;
    }

    $user = User::firstWhere('email', $sUser->email);

    if ($user) {
        return $this->createUser($provider, $sUser, $user);
    }

    return $this->createUser($provider, $sUser);
}

/**
 * If a User already exists for the email, skip user creation
 * and add this provider to the list of `$user->oauthProviders`.
 * @param  string $provider
 * @param  \Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User $sUser
 * @param \App\User $user
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function createUser($provider, $sUser, User $user = null)
{
    if (!$user) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $sUser->name,
            'email' => $sUser->email,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
        ]);
    } else if ($user->email_verified_at === null) {
        $user->email_verified_at = now();
        $user->save();
    }

    $user->oauthProviders()->create([
        'provider' => $provider,
        'provider_user_id' => $sUser->id,
        'access_token' => $sUser->token,
        'refresh_token' => $sUser->refreshToken ?? null,
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Before, it had a check for if `User::where('email', $sUser->email)`, and if so, reject the request with an "email already taken" message.

With the `oauth_providers` table and `$user->oauthProviders` relationship (User hasMany OAuthProviders), rather than create a new User in the users table every time someone uses oauth, it attaches that oauth record with the existing user `$user = User::firstWhere('email', $sUser->email);`

If anyone wants a little more, I modified this repo here to make both GitHub and Twitter oauth work: https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa. Base yourself around OAuthController.

With the above code, I can register a user via the registration form to capture an email, then login as GitHub and Twitter and have my user plus two oauth providers.

Most of the magic of my solution comes in with the 3rd param on `createUser`. It will remain to be seen if it works better to leave createUser as always creating, and then make a new method called addProviderToUser. That might be slightly more code, but it might also be simpler and more friendly to unit tests.

Here are my oauth redirect and callback methods too, for science reasons:

```
/**
 * Redirect the user to the provider authentication page. Twitter uses OAuth1.0a, and does not support
 * Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless(), so library `abraham/twitteroauth` is used to handle everything.
 *
 * @param  string $provider
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    if ($provider === 'twitter') {
        $tempId = Str::random(40);

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(config('services.twitter.client_id'), config('services.twitter.client_secret'));
        $requestToken = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => config('services.twitter.callback_url').'?user='.$tempId));

        \Cache::put($tempId, $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'], 86400); // 86400 seconds = 1 day

        $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $requestToken['oauth_token']));
    } else {
        $url = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
    }

    return [
        'url' => $url,
    ];
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from the provider.
 *
 * @param  string $driver
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider)
{
    if ($provider === 'twitter') {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(config('services.twitter.client_id'), config('services.twitter.client_secret'), $request->oauth_token, \Cache::get($request->user));
        $access_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/access_token', ['oauth_verifier' => $request->oauth_verifier]);

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(config('services.twitter.client_id'), config('services.twitter.client_secret'), $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials', ['include_email' => 'true']);

        $user->token = $access_token['oauth_token'];
    } else {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    }
    $user = $this->findOrCreateUser($provider, $user);

    $this->guard()->setToken(
        $token = $this->guard()->login($user)
    );

    return view('oauth/callback', [
        'token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => $this->guard()->getPayload()->get('exp') - time(),
    ]);
}
```

**config/services.php**

```
'github' => [
    'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'callback_url' => env('GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL'),
    'provider_name' => env('GITHUB_PROVIDER_NAME', 'GitHub'),
],

'twitter' => [
    'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'callback_url' => env('TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL'),
    'provider_name' => env('TWITTER_PROVIDER_NAME', 'Twitter'),
],
```

**.env**

```
# localhost
GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=
GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=
GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL=https://valet.test/api/oauth/github

TWITTER_CLIENT_ID=
TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET=
TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL=https://valet.test/api/oauth/twitter/callback
```

You'd have to look in the above sample repo to figure out how those env variables are being consumed, but hint: look at spa.blade.php, vuex, and api.php

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code to this:

```
$user = User::where('email', $SocialUser->email)->first();

if (!empty($user) && in_array($SocialUser->id, $user->provider_id) ) {

    session()->flash('message','Welcome to '.config('app.name').' '.$user->name);

    return $user;

}

if (empty($user) ) {

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $SocialUser->nickname?:$SocialUser->name,
        'slug' => str_slug($SocialUser->nickname?:$SocialUser->name).'-'.uniqid(),
        'email' => $SocialUser->email,
        'avatar' => $SocialUser->avatar,
        'profile' => Hash::make('no pic'),
        'password' => Hash::make('no need for password token based'),
        // 'website' => 'add a website',
        // 'github_profile' => 'add github profile',
       'email_notifications' => 1,
       'provider_id' => [$SocialUser->id]
    ]);

    $user->assignRole('user');

    \Mail::to($user)->send(new Welcome($user));

    session()->flash('message','Welcome to '.config('app.name').' '.$user->name);

    return $user;

}

$providers = array_push($user->provider_id, $SocialUser->id);

$user->update([
    'provider_id' => $providers
]);

session()->flash('message','Welcome to '.config('app.name').' '.$user->name);

return $user;
```

You are best also adding this to your User model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'provider_id' => 'array'
];
```

I hope this helps